# Lookup() function not working with Send Log DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to retrieve the 'view as web page' link that is stored under the Send Log Data extension, but I had no luck.

When I send an email to myself, the following attributes are showing correct values:

e.g.

- JobID
- SubscriberID
- _JobSubscriber

However, when I use a lookup function to find the 'view as web page' link in the send log DE, it seems like I am getting a NULL value.

Please review the code below and let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
%%[
SET @subscriber_key =[SubscriberKey]
SET @view_online = view_email_url
]%%

%%[
SET @JobID = JobID
SET @SubscriberID = SubscriberID
SET @BatchID = _JobSubscriberBatchID

IF _MessageContext == "VAWP" THEN
SET @view_as_web_page = LookUp('SendLogDE', 'view_online', 'SubID', @SubscriberID, 'JobID', @JobID, 'BatchID', @BatchID)
ELSE
SET @view_as_web_page = "https://fall-back-link.com"
ENDIF
]%%
```

Cheers,

Comment: I'm not completely sure but it might be a question of the processing order during the send process. If the view online link is created after the email content processing it can't be used within the content itself. Do you have values for the link in your sendlog?

Comment: Yes I am very confused on the purpose here? can't you just use`%%view_email_url%%` to get the VAWP link? Why do you need to do a lookup? Especially as @StephandePaly stated, the AMPscript is run prior to the send queue, meaning that the info on this send has not been pushed to the sendlog yet - which is why your lookup is failing.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington

Thank you for the response. The issue with %%view_email_url%% with my case is that there will just be one sendable data extension and this DE will gets refreshed everyday.

Hence, I was planning to use the following method:

[link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/sendTimeContent.htm)

Comment: Thanks @StephandePaly - I think you are right when you said it might be a question of the processing order. I was able to display both the jobid and the _JobSusbscriber value in the email, but not the custom field (e.g. view_online). There was a similar case raised here - [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270063/subscribers-view-email-url-link-breaking-frequently-randomly)

Comment: FYI - I have also found this link [Lookup to sendlog not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264566/lookup-to-sendlog-not-working)